Built a SQL query with some calculations in new columns. Now I want to query off those results. Possible?
I’ve built a query and done some calculations in new columns. Now, I only want to see a subset of that query in my final results. Is this where I would use a union?
SELECT BookValue, MarketValue, Allowance, MarketValue - (BookValue - Allowance) AS Unrealized 
FROM Holdings.table

^ this is the query I currently built but now I just want to see in my final results the records with an allowance that have Unrealized greater than 0.
Any suggestions?

MarketValue - (BookValue - Allowance) As Unrealized does not create a new column in your table. It only creates a column called Unrealized in your resultset

Note a table has rows, not records.

Take care if some of those columns are NULL. Are them? If so, what to do?

I would suggest investing some resources in some SQL professional development to build up your skills.

I suggest a [mre] for your future questions. You'll get assistance much faster and more accurately that way.

If your original query returned these 4 rows
Select BookValue, MarketValue, Allowance, MarketValue - (BookValue - Allowance) As Unrealized 
FROM Holdings.table




BookValue
MarketValue
Allowance
Unrealized




3
1
1
-1


2
1
1
0


1
1
1
1


1
1
2
2



If we then add a WHERE clause, we see only the 2 rows with Unrealized > 0
Select BookValue, MarketValue, Allowance, MarketValue - (BookValue - Allowance) As Unrealized 
FROM Holdings.table
WHERE MarketValue - (BookValue - Allowance) > 0 




BookValue
MarketValue
Allowance
Unrealized




1
1
1
1


1
1
2
2



Using a subquery would provide better performance because the calculation would only be performed one time per row instead of twice (once for SELECT
and once for WHERE).
SELECT * FROM
(
  Select BookValue, MarketValue, Allowance, MarketValue - (BookValue - Allowance) As Unrealized 
  FROM Holdingstable
) t
WHERE Unrealized > 0 

fiddle

Would I also need to include in my WHERE clause Allowance > 0?

@Bigcat1148 No, you would not need anything else.

No need for such a complicate WHERE clause or even a subquery, you can simply write ...HAVING Unrealized  > 0 , see https://dbfiddle.uk/Ty9Ha9Zl
